# Alternatives for usb_pipe_endpoint in older kernels

Tags: driver, kernel-module

I am building the device driver for a USB display on Ubuntu 10.04 (Kernel 2.6.32.52). According with the manufacturer the system has to have Git, Linux Headers, GCC, Binutils, and Make. I checked for all these things well. Then I downloaded the driver source code from the manufacturer github site, I cd to the driver directory and run make, but there are some errors and warnings:

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build KCPPFLAGS="-I/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src -I/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/../common" M=/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-52-generic'
Makefile:597: "WARNING: Appending $KCPPFLAGS (-I/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src -I/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/../common) from command line to kernel $CPPFLAGS"
  CC [M]  /home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.o
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c: In function ‘_status_start_querying’:
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:300: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_pipe_endpoint’
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:300: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c: In function ‘_on_release_disp_tickets_pool’:
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:866: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_free_coherent’
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c: In function ‘_on_alloc_disp_tickets_pool’:
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:905: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usb_alloc_coherent’
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:905: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.c:936: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘size_t’
make[2]: *** [/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/usbhandlers.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/someuser/rpusbdisp/drivers/linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-52-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I hope some one could provide me with some guide, what packages else should I check for, or if there are alternative function to use instead of ‘usb_pipe_endpoint’ and ‘usb_alloc_coherent’.

Thanks.

So I changed, usb_alloc_coherent with usb_buffer_alloc and usb_free_coherent with usb_buffer_free. It solves two of three errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install libusb too?

If not, install it `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev` then try a `make clean` and `make` again.

Just to add, revert those changes you made to those files as they're declared in usb.h (in libusb) too.

`git reset --hard` if you used git to clone it.

NOTE: That will reset ALL uncommitted git changes!

Comment: Hi. I just installed libusb-dev, but the errors (implicit declaration of function ‘usb_pipe_endpoint’, ‘usb_free_coherent’ and ‘usb_alloc_coherent’) keeps being generated. Should I include libusb on the source file?.

Comment: you shouldn't have to touch the source. What version of gcc and usblib are installed? and if this `rpusbdisp` is the one I found on GitHub earlier, i.e. here: https://github.com/robopeak/rpusbdisp

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Comment: gcc: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3, libusb-dev: 2:0.1.12-14ubuntu0.2. After running $dpkg-query -l 'libusb*', I got all these coincidences: libusb-0.1-4 2:0.1.12-14ubunt, libusb-1.0-0 2:1.0.6-1, libusb-1.0-0-dev 2:1.0.6-1, libusb-dev 2:0.1.12-14ubunt, libusb0

Comment: Yes, the github you point to, is the one I am trying to build.